# How can I get an iframe to work on both desktop/laptop and mobile devices?

Tags: ios, iframe, width

My site is [www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org](http://www.familyhistoryconferencenwq.org)

I have a MacBook Air, an iPhone 5 and an iPad Air so I phrase this for iOS 8.1.1 but obviously I want the solution to work for all tablets and smart phones across all platforms.

On the "Class Schedule" page of the site I have an iframe that works correctly on my MacBookAir running OS X Yosemite (10.1.1) but on my iPad Air and iPhone 5 running iOS 8.1.1 the frame width displays improperly. It extends to the right beyond the right edge of the page. If you visit the site on a a desktop or laptop then on a mobile device you should see what I mean.

My question is: what code do I use to get the iframe to display properly on mobile devices?

The relevant code is:

```
<div style="text-align: center"> 
<iframe src="url"; frame-border="1"; height="600px"; width="100%">
</iframe>
</div>
```

As I said, this code works correctly on the MacBook Air. The iframe occupies the width of the page. But on the iPhone and iPad the frame extends beyond the right border of the page. What am I doing wrong? (By the way, if I set the height to 100% I inexplicably get a frame about 200 px high although the source document takes 600px to view all of it.)

I've consulted two texts on HTML coding, searched other forum sites on the web and searched this site for the answer to similar questions but have had no luck. I've seen the item "Iframe on mobile devices problematic" on this site but I'm really hoping that I'm not stuck with that for an answer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best responsive iframe code I've come up with thus far is:

// HTML:

```
<div class="iframe-container iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350"
style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto;">

<iframe src="http://urlToTargetSite.com">

  <p style="font-size: 110%;"><em><strong>IFRAME:</strong> There is
  iframe content here but your browser version does not support
  iframes.</em> Please update your browser to its current version 
  and try again.</p>

</iframe>

</div>
```

// CSS:

```
.iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #7a8b8b;
  /* put following styles (necessary for overflow and
     scrolling handling) in div container around iframe
     because not stable in CSS
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     overflow: auto; */
}

.iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350 {
  padding: 10px 10px 70% 10px; /* padding-bottom = h/w as a % */
}
```

The rationale behind the code can be seen at [How To Make Responsive Iframes -- It's Easy!](http://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/)

There are three salient points:

1. Set *no* attributes in the iframe opening tag, specifically *not* width and height.
2. Put a div container around the iframe, and use CSS **height: 0;** and then **padding-bottom: nn%;** to give the container a height equal to the height:width ratio expressed as a percentage.
3. Style the div *inline* with **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;** and **overflow: auto;** which are necessary to handle scrolling and overflow on mobile devices and are unstable in CSS.